# Factoring Bivariate Polynomial which Vanishes on Curve

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Let $K$ be an infinite field, and let $f \in K[x,y]$. Suppose $f$ vanishes on $x = y$. Show that $x-y$ divides $f$.

I want to be able to use the division algorithm, so I first form the field of fractions of $K[x]$, denoted $K(x)$. Now, $K(x)[y]$ will be an Euclidean domain, and $f$ will be an element of it. These elements look like polynomials in $y$, with coefficients that are rational functions in $x$.  The division algorithm gives us $f(x,y) = (x-y)q(x,y) + r(x,y)$. But $d(x-y) = 1$, so $d(r(x,y))$ must be $0$, which is to say, $r(x,y)$ is just dependent on $x$.

From here, I am not completely sure where to go. I think that I can argue that $f(a,a) = (a - a)q(a,a) +r(a) = 0$ $\forall a \in K \rightarrow r(x) = 0$. What would be left is to show that all the coefficients of $q$ (which are in $K(x)$) have constant denominators, and I do not see a way to go about that.

Advice in any direction is appreciated.

Comment: You should  not pass from $K[x,y]$ to $K(x)[y]$: Euclid's division algorithm  is valid over a ring $A$  as long as you divide by a polynomial whose leading coefficient is invertible in $A$. In your case $A=K[y]$ and the leading coefficient of $x-y\in A[x]$ is $1$, thus invertible.